# JPA OneToOne mapping not using Foreign Key as specified

Tags: jpa, groovy, mapping, hibernate-mapping

So I am working on an issue in which the JPA mapping is trying to link two tables incorrectly.

The logic is something akin to:

```
@Table(name='TABLE_A')
class TableAEntity {
  @Id
  @Column(name = 'TABLE_A_ID')
  Long TableAId

  @Column(name='SOME_COLUMN_NAME')
  String someColumnName

  @Column(name='FOREIGN_KEY_ID')
  String foreignKeyId

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name='FOREIGN_KEY_ID',
  insertable=false, updatable=false)
  TableBEntity tableB
}

@Table(name='TABLE_B')
class TableBEntity {
  @Id
  @Column(name = 'TABLE_B_ID')
  Long TableBId

  @Column(name='SOME_COLUMN_NAME')
  String someColumnName

  @Column(name='SOME_OTHER_COLUMN_NAME')
  String someOtherColumnName

  @Column(name = 'FOREIGN_KEY_ID')
  String foreignKeyId
}
```

From everything I have read through similar questions in Stackoverflow and other help sites and document sites, this is arguably correct.

Where my issue comes into play, is that the query is doing something odd every other time, but working correctly the other part of the time. When it is not working correctly, it tries to join like so:

```
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B tableb_0
WHERE tableb_0.foreign_key_id = ?
```

Whereas the `?` in this is `null`

Now `foreignKeyId` in TABLE B is a Column with a unique constraint and Table A has a foreign Key relationship to this Column in Table B.

I have tried:

- setting fetch type to Lazy (no changes)
- changing TABLE A to use mappedBy and setting up a bidirectional mapping in Table B (get an inaccessible error)
- adding `referencedColumn`
- a number of other configurations I found browsing stackoverflow and a number of other websites

At this point the mapping, when called, will either perform correctly, or will try to nulled variation...

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong or how to resolve this?

Comment: Have you copied the mapping from somewhere? I'm seeing more and more people setting insertable and updatable to false with the extra foreign key column.  It shouldn't be necessary unless you are trying to map some peculiar use case.

Comment: Yes, i copied existing logic that all other entities were using to maintian consistency. I am still a little new to JPA, so i wasnt certain how necesary these where. Do you think the updatable and insertable being removed would make a difference?

Comment: Hard to say, but I've just noticed that   `String foreignKeyId` is a `String` but the id in `TableBEntity` is a long. THat doesn't seem right. If I were you I would follow the guide and try the mapping I've suggested in my answer.

Comment: I think they've set insertable and updatable to false because they've mapped the column with the foreign key as an extra attribute. But I doubt you need it and if you need the id you can always get it via `a.getTableB().getId()`. Anyway, the type should match with the id in `TableBEntity`

Comment: They are probably using the extra column because this way they can create the object from the JSON

Answer (score 0):

A unidirectional one-to-one is usually mapped this way:

```
@Entity
@Table(name='TABLE_A')
class TableAEntity {
  @Id
  @Column(name = 'TABLE_A_ID')
  Long tableAId

  @Column(name='SOME_COLUMN_NAME')
  String someColumnName

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name='FOREIGN_KEY_ID')
  TableBEntity tableB

   // hascode/equals
}

@Entity
@Table(name='TABLE_B')
class TableBEntity {
  @Id
  @Column(name = 'TABLE_B_ID')
  Long tableBId

  @Column(name='SOME_COLUMN_NAME')
  String someColumnName

  @Column(name='SOME_OTHER_COLUMN_NAME')
  String someOtherColumnName

   // hascode/equals
}
```

I'd say check the Hibernate ORM documentation on how to map associations with [@OneToOne](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one) if you want more examples.

You can also use [@MapsId](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-derived) if you want to remove the extra column on `TABLE_A`

Comment: Sorry, your answer made me realize I had typos. I updated with corrections and new information I found while troubleshooting.